# Kendo UI Scheduler wrong date format G

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, scheduler

My project is on asp.net mvc. I'm using Kendo Ui to create scheduler. Why do i get an error "invalid date format string 'G'"? Why do I get format equals to "G"? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. The list of patterns of culture i'm using didn't have such kind of date format as "G". I just added it.

Comment: It sounds like reasonable.